# How to fix that new users show up again in subsite of a Multisite?

Tags: multisite, users, user-registration

When I add a new user in multisite, the user is successfully displayed in multisite super admin environment.

But when I go to the subsite where I want to add this user, the new added user doesn’t show up. (In the database the new user exists.)

Do you have an idea, why this happens?

(Additional background explanation: I exported the subsite from another multisite environment to a single site and imported it to the new multisite environment. So I am not sure if the error happend because of that. The old users are all there and everything is fine with that.)

Answer (score 1):

That its expected behaviour, you have to manually add the user to the site and select his role, you go to `All Sites`, Edit a site, then select the `Users`, tab:

[image]

Comment: You can also add the user to a site in the site's **Users** admin page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem was different, but somehow it seems to work now. So I consider it solved for now.